# Is there a zsh built-in which will allow me to stream log-lines is a nicely formatted table

Tags: macos, shell, logging, streaming, zsh

I have a log-file with `|` delimited "columns" that I wish to **stream** log-lines from like this:

```
$ tail -f log.log

2021-01-01 | filename | LogText
2021-01-02 | really-long-filename/with/path | LogText
2021-01-03 | filename | LogText that is really really really long and will wrap over the
end of the line.
2021-01-04| filename | LogText>
```

I'd like to display this in a more tabular format, padding the contents of each "column" and wrapping intelligently so the output from above looks more like this:

```
$ tail -f log.log | <SOME-COMMAND>
2021-01-01 | filename.txt                     | LogText
2021-01-02 | really/long/path/to/filename.txt | LogText
2021-01-03 | filename.txt                     | LogText that is really really really long 
                                                and will wrap over the end of the line
2021-01-01 | filename.txt                     | LogText
```

I could do this "manually" using `awk` or `sed` but is there a command line tool *[edit: reword for clarity]* that I can use to get what I want rather than re-inventing the wheel?

I tried piping to `column -t` but it seems it has 2 limitations:

- the mac(zsh) `column` can't stream results to the terminal so if you "follow" log lines into `column` like this: `tail -f log.log | column -t` instead getting a table of logs where each new log is appended to the end of the table there is no output on the terminal.
- the mac(zsh) `column` doesn't allow text wrapping of columns

```
$ cat log.log | column -W -t
column: illegal option -- W
```

Comment: `column` is independent of `zsh`; it's the BSD version of `column` that doesn't support text-wrapping. You can always install the GNU version and use that instead.

Comment: BTW, `column` and `tail` are not internal ("built-in") commands either.  Why are you against using using external commands? If you reall want to implement **everything** inside zsh alone, you would have to implement it by yourself, i.e. create zsh functions which perform the task.

Comment: ah. I think too much emphasis has been put on my use of "built-in" here. I meant is there a command line tool (either installable or built-in) that does what I want.

@chepner I'm struggling to understand how to install GNU column - `brew install column / gcolumn / gnucolumn` aren't yielding results - what should I be searching for?